# css affecting all the tables in my site, how do avoid this?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have this CSS for one table, but it seems to affect all the other tables I have on my site.

CSS code example:

```
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
/*effects map*/
td {
 background:#555;
```

And some example HTML:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle">


            <td class="firstColumn">data1</td>
            <td class="secondColumn">data2</td>
```

Comment: add another class to your table in which table you want to add css and in css give effect for this class. Ex:  <table class ="a">...</table> and Css like table.a tr:last-child td:last-child{..}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a class on the table you want to apply this specific CSS and rewrite your css to look like this:

```
.mySpecialTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
/*effects map*/
.mySpecialTable td {
 background:#555;
```

More: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/getting-selective-css-styling/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
.accordion-toggle tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
/*effects map*/
.firstColumn td {
 background:#555;
}
```